# Undefined control sequence \documentclass

Tags: compiling

First of all I would like to thank you because you helped me out a lot with all your answers to the already online questions.

Now, here is my problem. I am trying to do a bibliography file with TeXworks but I get this error when I try to compile (pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+bibTeX):

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
    entering extended mode
    ****PATH here******
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    l.1 \documentclass
        [a4paper,11pt]{report}
```

I've been reading some similar questions but I don't find the way to fix it (maybe I am missing something). I found one that says that I am trying to compile a LaTeX file using TeX compiler but I don't know how to change the configuration.

This is the .bib fiel content:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}     % faire de l'anglais
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % accents dans le source
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % accents dans le DVI
    \usepackage{url}
    \begin{document}

    @Article{ref11,
author={Danihelka, Jiri and Kencl, Lukas},
journal={Cloud Futures Workshop 2012 },
title={Colaborative 3D Environments over Windows Azure},
year={2012},
month={May},
pages={},
note={}
    }

    @book{ref12,
author = {Lee, Henry and Chuvyrov, Eugene},
    title = {Beginning Windows Phone 7 Development},
    publisher = {Apress},
    volume = {},
    number = {},
    series = {},
    address = {},
    edition = {Second edition},
    year = {2011},
    month = {July},
    note = {}
    }

    @Article{ref13,
author={},
journal={},
title={Cloud computing},
year={},
month={},
pages={},
url={\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing}}
    }

    \end{document}
```

Comment: You are running pdfTeX, not pdfLaTeX. Check _carefully_ which option you have selected in TeXworks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: As I said, I am using pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+bibTeX to compile.
If I go to preferences->compile, and I edit the option pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+bibTeX, this are the parameters:

Program: texify.exe
Parameters: --pdf
--tex-option=$synctexoption
$fullname

What should I change?

Comment: Can you give us some more background? Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that exhibits this problem.

Comment: @jlcivico Your .bib file should not contain `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, etc.; only bibtex/biblatex entries!

Comment: look into your documents source with another Editor and control if you have a first line like `%& tex` if yes, delete it and it will then use `latex`

Comment: @JosephWright  Wow, just a big silly error. I am following a template and when I open it on TeXworks it showed the pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+bibTeX without realising that this is the default option of the program and I thought that this way the right way to compile. Now, if I choose pdfLaTeX all goes smooth.

In spite of that, I try to include the bibliography to my tex file but it does not appear.

        \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
        \bibliography{bibliograhy/biblio}

(bilbio.bib file is in /bibliography folder)

Comment: jlcivico retain the incorrect .bib contents in question so that another user in same situation will benefit with your mistakes. Did @Jubobs answer work for you ?

Comment: I don't know if I am wrong but, is it possible to compile the .bib file using pdfLaTeX and then include it on my report.tex ?
Because maybe the concept is the basis of my error.

Comment: @jlcivico run `pdflatex`, `bibtex`,`pdflatex` and `pdflatex` sequence. Note: `pdflatex` does not run `.bib` files instead looks for `.bbl`file generated by `bibtex`.

Comment: @texenthusiast When I run bibtex it shows the next message: The top-level auxiliary file: biblio.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file biblio.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file biblio.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file biblio.aux
It is supposed that in the first run of pdflatex, it should place these lines into biblio.aux

Comment: @jlcivico In TeXworks,File menu--> remove old auxillary .aux files and rerun `pdflatex`, `bibtex`,`pdflatex` and `pdflatex` sequence. Jubobs answer works well. For reference: verify with [andy-roberts bibliographies .tex example](http://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/bib.tex) and [sample.bib](http://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/sample.bib)

Comment: @texenthusiast Ok, after changing the compilation mode in texmaker it works. It shows the bibliography on my report.tex but it does not create the auxiliary files.

Comment: @jlcivico are you using TeXworks or Texmaker ? both would work with default configuration. once you get the sufficient reputation you can come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) it is not recommended to have more comments here as TeX.SX recommends a chat discussion.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Your .bib file should **only** contain BibTeX entries (and possibly comments). It should **not** contain `\documentclass`, `\usepackage`, `\begin{document}`, etc.

If your .bib file has "mybiblio" as base name and contains

```
@Article{ref11,
    author  = {Danihelka, Jiri and Kencl, Lukas},
    journal = {Cloud Futures Workshop 2012 },
    title   = {Colaborative 3D Environments over Windows Azure},
    year    = {2012},
    month   = {May},
    pages   = {},
    note    = {}
}

@book{ref12,
    author      = {Lee, Henry and Chuvyrov, Eugene},
    title       = {Beginning Windows Phone 7 Development},
    publisher   = {Apress},
    volume      = {},
    number      = {},
    series      = {},
    address     = {},
    edition     = {Second edition},
    year        = {2011},
    month       = {July},
    note        = {}
}

@Article{ref13,
    author  = {},
    journal = {},
    title   = {Cloud computing},
    year    = {},
    month   = {},
    pages   = {},   
    url = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing}}
}
```

then running `pdflatex`, then `bibtex`, then `pdflatex` twice on the following code should work and produce the expected output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}     % faire de l'anglais
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % accents dans le source
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % accents dans le DVI
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

As seen in \cite{ref11}, blah blah blah.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybiblio}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May be it's worthwhile to mention run `pdflatex` first, then `bibtex` again `pdflatex` and again `pdflatex` to get the final pdf with citations for a new user.