# "Undefined control sequence" on auto-generated tex files

Tags: errors, pdftex, compiling, cygwin

I'm using *ipython-notebook* to convert my code to `tex` file and then to a `pdf` file, and an issue occurred when converting from the generated `tex` file to `pdf` (I've posted an issue [**here**](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5485)). The whole generated tex file is **[here](http://codepad.org/FwOInyra)**.

Then I tried to find some other tools to convert `tex` to `pdf`, and I found `pdftex` under my `cygwin\bin` path (I'm on windows7), then I tried it, and again got errors:

```
D:\Documents\Desktop> pdftex CSMATH-hw1.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Cygwin)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./CSMATH-hw1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10     \documentclass
                       [letterpaper,10pt,english]{d:/Anaconda/lib/site-packa...

?
! Undefined control sequence.
l.13     \usepackage
                    [utf8]{inputenc}
```

I've searched the tex.sx and find this [**post**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102886/undefined-control-sequence-documentclass) referred to `pdfTeX` and `pdfLaTeX`, but I don't find a `pdfLaTex.exe` on my machine. Thx in advance ;)

### EDIT:

I found file `D:\cygwin\bin\pdflatex` on my machine, and find there is only one line in that file:

```
!<symlink>pdftex.exe
```

Then I try it in the *cygwin terminal*, like this:

```
zhangxaochen@zhangxaochen-PC /cygdrive/d/Documents/Desktop
$ pdflatex CSMATH-hw1.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Cygwin)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./CSMATH-hw1.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `d:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/sphinx/texinputs/sphinxhowto
.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:
```

The file `"d:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/sphinx/texinputs/sphinxhowto.cls"` **does exist** in my pc, so why I get such an error? Is it because of the Windows style path being not recognized?

### EDIT2:

Indeed `cygwin` needs the *nix style path, I edited the path like:

```
d:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/sphinx/texinputs/sphinxhowto
```

to:

```
/cygdrive/d/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/sphinx/texinputs/sphinxhowto
```

and now I can generate an pdf file from cygwin terminal, despite the Chinese characters could not be shown correctly:

```
! Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 19968 = U+4E00,
(ucs)                possibly declared in uni-78.def.
(ucs)                Type H to see if it is available with options.

See the ucs package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.300 ...e, 浠ュ強鐢熸垚鐨勫甫鍣０鐐逛釜鏁▒ n, }

? h
Unicode character 19968 = U+4E00:
Contained in range 'CJK Ideograph'
Character available with following options:
   cjkbg5, cjkgb, cjkjis.
Enter I!<RET> to define the glyph.
? I!<ret>
Please enter definition for unicode character 19968

\definition=
```

Comment: You should really use `pdflatex`.  What TeX distribution do you have?  How did you install it?  It should be in the same place as `pdftex`...

Comment: @zhangxaochen I can compile your file with pdflatex even though  figures can't be shown, and I am on Mac so I don't have the right font but I am sure you be fine with pdflatex.

Comment: @mbork `pdflatex` is simply a `!<symlink>pdftex.exe` in cygwin, see my edit plz

Comment: try specifing path using \\ ?

Comment: @zhangxaochen although pdflatex is a link to pdftex it matters which you use as the underlyng executable acts differently depending on the name by which it was called. Presumably the class is not in TeX's search path try export TEXINPUTS=/cygdrive/d/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/sphinx/texinputs:  ; pdflatex CSMATH-hw1

Comment: @alexises I tried `"\\"`, and it didn't work. I had to change path to `/cygdrive/d/...`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thx for your reply, now my problem becomes latex with Chinese, and I'm googling to solve it ;)